# Devexpress IntelliSense in markup

Tags: asp.net, intellisense, devexpress

I've got problem with IntelliSense in markup for example:

When I type

```
<dxwgv:ASPxGridView ID="grid" runat="server">
   <Columns>
      < -- here I hit ctrl + space and only normla html tags are shown: a, abbr ... --
      But I would like to have available columns instead :/
   </Columns>
</ dxwgv:ASPxGridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intellisense is a VS feature and we cannot do much here ... Anyway, if you type the

```
  <dxwgv:
```

in the columns section and press the Ctrl+Space, the VS should be be able to show the list of available column classes.